# Snakemake process Kllled

Tags: python, out-of-memory, hpc, snakemake

I am trying to run a `Snakefile`, which I checked that works for a small number of files, but it keeps giving me this error when I try to run it using a bigger number of input files:

```sh
Building DAG of jobs...
Killed
```

As a clarification, I have 726 protein files and 19634 hmm files.

The `snakefile` looks like this:

```py
ARCHIVE_FILE = 'output.tar.gz'

# a single output file
OUTPUT_FILE = 'output_{hmm}/{species}_{hmm}.out'

# a single input file
INPUT_FILE = 'proteins/{species}.fasta'

# a single hmm file
HMM_FILE = 'hmm/{hmm}.hmm'

# a single cat file
CAT_FILE = 'cat/cat_{hmm}.txt'

# a single lines file
LINE_FILE = 'lines/lines_{hmm}.txt'

# a single bit file
BIT_FILE = 'bit_scores/bit_{hmm}.txt'

# Build the list of input files.
INP = glob_wildcards(INPUT_FILE).species

# Build the list of hmm files.
HMM = glob_wildcards(HMM_FILE).hmm

# The list of all output files
OUT = expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm=HMM)

# The list of all CAT files
CAT = expand(CAT_FILE, hmm=HMM)

# The list of all lines files
LINE = expand(LINE_FILE, hmm=HMM)

# The list of all lines files
BIT = expand(BIT_FILE, hmm=HMM)

# pseudo-rule that tries to build everything.
# Just add all the final outputs that you want built.
rule all:
    input: ARCHIVE_FILE

# hmmsearch
rule hmm:
    input:
        species=INPUT_FILE ,
        hmm=HMM_FILE
    output: 
        OUTPUT_FILE,
    params:
        cmd='hmmsearch --noali -E 99 --tblout'
    shell: 
        '{params.cmd} {output} {input.hmm} {input.species} '

# concatenate output per hmm
rule concatenate:
    input:
        expand(OUTPUT_FILE, species=INP, hmm="{hmm}"),
    output:
        CAT_FILE,
    params:
        cmd="cat",
    shell:
        "{params.cmd} {input} > {output} "

# clean cat files
rule clean_cats:
    input:
        cmd='/home/agalvez/bin/remove_lines_starting_with_#.pl',
        values=CAT_FILE
    output: LINE_FILE
    shell: 
        '{input.cmd} -input {input.values} -output {output}'

# create an archive with all results
rule create_archive:
    input: OUT, CAT, LINE,
    output: ARCHIVE_FILE
    shell: 'tar -czvf {output} {input}'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably look for an OOM in the system logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can concatenate all the protein sequences into a single fasta file and run that against the hmm profiles. In this way you have 19634 jobs instead of 19634 x 726. But I think you can also combine the hmm profiles into a single file and have a single `hmmsearch` job.

Besides, even if you succeed running snakemake the way you plan, working with 14M files is going to be terrible. I don't know... but I feel what you are trying to do, running many proteins against many profiles, is not unusual but you are making things more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Given the numbers in the question, there will be `14,254,284` files in `OUTPUT_FILE` (and since each one is created by a rule, that many rule instances, not considering the other rules). This is probably still feasible, but it matters also where you run the `snakemake`. If you are running this on a login node of a cluster, then typically the resources of a login node are not sufficient to run large workflows and the process will be killed due to insufficient memory.

Some of the options are:

- run the workflow on a machine that has sufficient RAM (e.g. get a long-running compute node just for snakemake);
- re-format the workflow to batch certain combinations (potentially rule `concatenate` could be combined with rule `hmm` , but depends on how resource-intensive rule `hmm` is);
- run only part of the workflow at a time.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense thanks. In fact, I was trying the second option but I do not understand why now it is not being able to work even in just 2 hmm files... I tested it previously with 10 files and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Generally this is not a good idea, but you might want to clear out previous metadata by deleting the hidden `.snakemake` folder... but as always, one needs to be careful with deleting data, and to make backups, where appropriate.